# Complex Numbers Problems

Tags: complex-numbers

I have a problem that I need help with - 
Find the number of complex numbers $z$ such that
$z^{2018} =\overline{z}$

So far, I've converted each side to complex exponential form ($re^{n*i*\theta}$), but I'm not sure how to continue...

Thanks! Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say that $$z = re^{i \theta}$$
So the equation becomes 
$$r^n e^{in\theta} = re^{-i\theta}$$
where $n = 2018$.
This means that $r = \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$ and 
$$n\theta  = -\theta + 2k\pi \qquad k \in \lbrace 0\ldots n \rbrace$$
or $$(n+1)\theta = 2k\pi \qquad k \in \lbrace 0\ldots n \rbrace $$
which means that 
$$\theta = \frac{2k\pi}{n+1}  \qquad k \in \lbrace 0\ldots n \rbrace$$
which gives you $$n-0+1 = n+1 = 2018+1 = 2019$$ 
So in total you have $2019 + 1 = 2020$ solutions.

Comment: Hmm... can $r$ not equal to $0$ as well?

Comment: yep you're right .. i have edited

Comment: Thank you! I see. Have a great day!

Comment: if you find the solution useful you could upvote and mark it as correct for others to know that it was helpful

Comment: Will do :) @Ahmad

Answer (score 1):

One solution to $z^n=\bar{z}$ is $z=0$ (where $n$ is any positive integer). Suppose $z\ne0$; then
$$
|z^{n}|=|\bar{z}|
$$
implies $|z|=1$ (why?).

Therefore $\bar{z}=z^{-1}$ and the equation becomes
$$
z^{n+1}=1
$$

How many $(n+1)$-th roots of unity are there?